# Calling functions in tkinter

Tags: function, user-interface, python-3.x, menu, tkinter

For the line:

```
 file_Menu.add_command(label = 'New', command = do_Nothing)
```

why is the function called `command = do_Nothing` instead of `command = do_Nothing()` ?

The entire code is below:

```
# Tkinter GUI Menu

from tkinter import *

### Functions ###

# Do Nothing
def do_Nothing():
    print('I just did... nothing')



### Create tkinter window ###

# Create Window
root = Tk() 



#### Creating the Menu(s) ###

# Create the Menu Bar
menu_Bar = Menu(master = root)

# Create File Menu
file_Menu = Menu(master = menu_Bar)



### Displaying the Menu(s) ###

# Display Menu Bar
root.config(menu = menu_Bar)

# Display File Menu
menu_Bar.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = file_Menu)




### File Menu Properties ####

# New
file_Menu.add_command(label = 'New', command = do_Nothing)

# Open
file_Menu.add_command(label = 'Open', command = do_Nothing)

# Exit
file_Menu.add_command(label = 'Exit', command = root.quit) 




### Display tkinter window ###
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter is normal python, so it follows normal python rules: if you use a function name followed by parenthesis, python will immediately execute that function and return the result.

So, when you do this:

```
file_Menu.add_command(..., command = do_Nothing())
```

... it is exactly the same as if you did this:

```
nothing = do_Nothing()
file_Menu.add_command(..., command = nothing)
```

When you specify a command in a binding or `command` callback, you must tell tkinter the *name* of the command (or more accurately, a *reference* to the command).